# Craft Installation - Getting a Forbidden Error

Tags: config

A forbidden error appears and can't get it to disappear. I've gone through the installation process several times and everything else works.

When I load the URL "test.craft.dev", I get back `"Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server."`

Things I've tried:

1) db.php

```
$craftPath = '../craft';
```

2) folder structure

```
/craft/..
/public/index.php
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

When I get this error it is usually because the top craft directory isn't readable. When you unzip the original craft zip file, you get something like this:

```
drwx------@ 5 m  staff       170 Jul  8 14:47 Craft-2.1.2563
```

And that top directory (the one that contains craft and public) needs to be readable by apache.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure I understand your folder structure, but as long as the `craft/` folder is exactly one level above your `public/index.php` file, then the `$craftPath` setting you currently have will work.

The specific error message you are getting isn't coming from Craft... it's coming from Apache and will be related to how your server environment is currently setup.

There are some great threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551840/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server) that should get you going in the right direction on how to resolve it.